# Server is sending parameters to the URL

Tags: laravel, api, post, server, parameters

Server team confirmed the parameters sent by server: "Dec 12 16:41:54 x1 wcron: [-] postNtimes: Posting done, url= b'wubook.revroo.io/push-notification';, params= {'rcode': 1670859713, 'lcode': 1669807740}".(https://tdocs.wubook.net/wired/fetch.html#setting-up-the-push-notification)

There are 2 params that are sending to my url(rcode, lcode) but my code can't received it.

```
public function url(Request $request)
    {
        $lcode = $request->has('lcode') ? $request->lcode : null;
        $rcode = $request->has('rcode') ? $request->rcode : null;

        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <methodResponse>
        <param>
            <value>
            <int>" . $lcode . "</int>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
            <int>" . $rcode . "</int>
            </value>
        </param>
    </methodResponse>";
        $response = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        return response([$lcode, $rcode], 200);
        return xmlrpc_decode($response);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace these lines:

```
$lcode1 =  $request->request->get('lcode');
$rcode1 =  $request->request->get('rcode');
```

with these lines:

```
$lcode1 =  $request['lcode'];
$rcode1 =  $request['rcode'];
```

Comment: Tried, Still couldn't receive the params.